# If I use Apple Tv as a separate display on Mavericks will it transfer sound

Tags: macos, display, appletv

I want to get an apple tv, so I can wirelessly use my tv as a separate monitor, now with mavericks I know this is supported. I was wondering if this means I can also transfer any sounds from my computer to my tv, otherwise it's sorta not worth getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AirPlay mirroring sends video and sound to the connected device.

You can over-ride the sound if needed by selecting an alternate output as well as just send sound to any AirPlay receiver as well.

This is how [AirPlay has worked](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5404?) since it started with sound and the video mirroring support keeps adding features as time goes by.

Comment: I'm not mirroring though using as a separate space

Comment: Your sound transfers to the Apple TV upon connecting and then you can over-ride it if needed. The mirror / extend toggle doesn't affect things. I agree that would be less useful if you couldn't get better sound when AirPlay was on.

Comment: sounds good I'll probably accept this, it would be annoying if they added the support for appletv as a separate display and didn't allow sound to transfer through as well